# operator is treated as a variable in SQL

Tags: sql

I am having a problem where the user passes any operator below <,>,<=,>=,= and then uses it to create a where condition.

```
create  function salary(@salary int, @operator char(2))
returns table
return select dbo.NHANVIEN.HOTEN, dbo.NHANVIEN.LUONG from dbo.NHANVIEN
(case @sosanh when '>' then  (where @sosanh+ @mucluong) end )
```

this is not possible
or

```
create function salary(@salary int, @operator char(2))
returns @table table(name nvarchar(10), luong int)
as
begin
if(@operator = '>')
begin
insert into @table
select dbo.NHANVIEN.HOTEN, dbo.NHANVIEN.LUONG from dbo.NHANVIEN where dbo.NHANVIEN.LUONG > @salary 
end
if(@operator = '<')
begin
insert into @table
select dbo.NHANVIEN.HOTEN, dbo.NHANVIEN.LUONG from dbo.NHANVIEN where dbo.NHANVIEN.LUONG < @salary 
end
.........
end
```

can't this really be faster than this?

Comment: If you really don't want to repeat the code, then research dynamic SQL - but **also** how to avoid SQL injection. How to do either depends on your specific implementation of SQL, which you didn't tag.

Comment: Instead of passing an operator, pass a range of values that the salary must fall in and always do `WHERE salary >= @rangeStart AND salary < @rangeEnd` (exclusive ranges are easier to manage). Open ranges can be presented using values like 0 and 2147483647 (assuming nobody earns a negative salary). If the operator approach must be maintained, constructing these values based on the operator isn't difficult.

Comment: i'm a student i just learned sql this is an exercise i have to do and i've been trying just to be able to repeat the code like way 2 i can do

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL  server but I already have the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it waht you want

```
create  function salary(@salary int, @operator char(2))
returns table
return 
  select nh.HOTEN, nh.LUONG 
  from dbo.NHANVIEN nh
  where (@operator = '>' and nh.LUONG > @salary
     or  @operator = '<' and nh.LUONG < @salary
     ...
     )
```